# Can I read the contents of a directory using HTML5?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, filesystems, directory

I am currently using the drag and drop functionality of HTML5 to allow users to add local files and folders.

I was wondering if it is possible to read the contents within a folder that is dragged in and display each file within it in some kind of list?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<div id="drop_zone"></div>

<script>
var dropzone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
  var length = e.dataTransfer.items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var entry = e.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (entry.isFile) {
        alert("a file");
    } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
        alert('Directory: ' + entry.fullPath);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks